# RxJava+Android+GreenDao : Cascade delete multiple entities

Tags: android, rx-java

I have 2 tables in database, Course and Lecture. They are 1:N relationship. My problem is I want to delete multiple courses, before that I  have to make sure all its relative Lectures are deleted, as well as some files along with the lecture. That is, I want to delete multiple course, for every course, the following steps should be perform:

1. delete lecture file and record delete course
2. delete course

How to do it with RxJava 1.x?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be like :

```
    ArrayList<Course> courses = new ArrayList<>();
    Observable.fromIterable(courses)
            .doAfterNext(new Consumer<Course>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(Course course) throws Exception {
                    //DELETE this Course
                }
            }).flatMap(new Function<Course, ObservableSource<ArrayList<Lecture>>>() {
                @Override
                public ObservableSource<ArrayList<Lecture>> apply(Course course) throws Exception {
                    return Observable.fromArray(course.getAllLecture());
                }
            })
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Consumer<ArrayList<Lecture>>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(ArrayList<Lecture> lectures) throws Exception {
                    //delete all lectures
                }
            });
```

Comment: Thx, doAfterNext? is it doOnNext or doAfterTerminate? I'm using rxjava 1.x

Comment: DoAfterNext will be executed after onNext(here is delete lectures) , so....

Answer (score 0):

If you're using GreenDao, I don't think that using RxJava in this way is your best bet. Your major problem here is that you're not in a transaction, which leaves you at risk of your data ending up in an inconsistent state.  While it can be a great exercise to consider, "how can I write this code in Rx style?" I suggest that it doesn't gain you anything to use it for every step of this process.  Therefore, I suggest you write your delete code as procedural (not Rx) code inside of a GreenDao transaction, and only use RxJava to be notified when it is completed. When you are inside of a GreenDao transaction block, all of the database calls inside of it are made synchronously, one after another, in guaranteed order.

In addition, for the greatest consistency, I would delete all of the files at once only after the transaction block is committed (because you may not want to delete the files if part of the DB transaction fails and the database doesn't update). In addition, there are two major ways of doing deletes in GreenDao: directly, `session.delete(entity)` and queries, `query.buildDelete().tableDeleteQuery.executeDeleteWithoutDetachingEntities()`. Direct deletes are much simpler to code, but could be slower if you have huge amounts of data. If you have less than 1000 very simple entities, direct deletes are probably good enough.
So, your code might look like this:

```
final DaoSession daoSession = getDaoSession();
final List<Course> courses = getCoursesToDelete();
// rxTx() creates a tx that runs on RxJava's 'io' scheduler.
daoSession.rxTx().call(() -> {
    List<File> filesToDelete = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Course course : courses) {
        for(Lecture lecture : course.getLectures()) {
            filesToDelete.add(lecture.getFiles());
            daoSession.delete(lecture);
        }
        daoSession.delete(course);
    }
    return filesToDelete;
})
// potentially handle DB errors here
// .flatMapIterable here if you want each File as an Rx event
.doOnNext(filesToDelete -> {
    for(File f : filesToDelete) {
        // Throw on failed delete here if needed
        f.delete();
    }
})
// handle file delete errors if desired.
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()) // technically redundant
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribe();
```